# How do i store two values into variables from two entries with a single button press?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

This is my first python application guys so don't laugh if the answer is obvious.

I need to get from 2 entries 2 values and then store them into variables with a single button press. I use tkinter to design my GUI. I am able to make the button store the value entered in 'entry1' in the variable entry1 but cannot make the button store a second one at the same time.

TLDR:
when button press
   text from entry1 gets stored into entry1 variable
   text from entry2 gets stored into entry2 variable

Below you will find the code that i am using for only 1 action (get the text from entry1 in entry1 variable)

```
def get_code_cl(entry1):
  print(entry1)
def get_Dade_cl(entry):
  print(entry2)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Search",bg='red',font=20,fg='white', command=lambda: get_code_cl(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.01, relheight=0.23, relwidth=0.11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow florin!

To solve your problem you can make the command of the button a subroutine that creates both of the variables.

For example, in the example code below, the button's command is the storevaluessubroutine subroutine.

This subroutine creates two variables: 'entry1value' and 'entry2value' that store the values of the 'entry1' and 'entry2' entry fields.

I made the entry1 and entry2 entry fields global entry fields so that their values can be fetched in the storevaluessubroutine subroutine.

```
global entry1
entry1 = Entry(frame)
entry1.pack()

global entry2
entry2 = Entry(frame)
entry2.pack()

def storevaluessubroutine():
    entry1value = entry1.get()
    entry2value = entry2.get()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Search",bg='red',font=20,fg='white', command=storevaluessubroutine)
button.place(relx=0.21, rely=0.01, relheight=0.23, relwidth=0.11)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Good to keep this in mind for next projects. 
Thanks a lot Tom!!

Comment: No problem, im happy to help. Florin, make sure to click the tick next to answers to accept them!